# java.sql.Timestamp to Joda Instant and vice versa

Tags: java, jodatime, sql-timestamp

Is this possible? I found a few solution for converting to and from localDateTime like can be seen [here](http://www.roytuts.com/conversion-of-joda-date-time-to-sql-timestamp-and-vice-versa/)

But I can't find a solution for Joda Instant...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the epoch millis to convert:

```
Timestamp ts = ....;
Instant i = new Instant(ts.getTime());
Timestamp ts2 = new Timestamp(i.getMillis());
```